# mod-rewrite: what's wrong with this simple rewrite to redirect to a subdirectory?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, wordpress, directory

The root directory (`http://www.example.com`) has a catch all `index.php` page in it, and an `.htaccess` file. Within this root directoy I have a `wordpress/` directory which contains (suprise surprise) a Wordpress installation.

My goal is that when the user types in `http://www.example.com` they are instead taken to `http://www.example.com/wordpress`

Here is my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/wordpress/$1 [L]
```

At the moment it appears to do nothing - it still loads `index.php` within the root directory.

What should my rewrite rule be (I'm assuming the one I'm using is wrong)?

Comment: Server's tech support suggested 'Redirect permanent /index.php http:// www. mydomain. com/wordpress' but that won't work because you'll always have 'wordpress' in the user's address bar. They shouldn't be seeing 'wordpress' in there at all...

Comment: Furthermore, that only works for calls to index.php. What about calls to, say, wp-login.php etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Correct way to use WordPress in its own directory is to copy the index.php file from the WordPress directory and change the line this line:

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

To this:

```
require('./your_wordpress_directory/wp-blog-header.php');
```

When you do this go back to your admin options and re save your permalinks and WordPress will automatically rewrite your .htaccess based on your site url and WordPress url options selected.

These can also be defined in wp-config.php

Use this if WordPress lives at http://example.com/wordpress but you want users to access your site by typing in example.com.

`define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com')`;

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress');
```

Comment: Outstanding. I had read the instructions on moving index.php out of the wordpress/ directory, but making WP_HOME different from WP_SITEURL was the missing link! Rather than hard-code it in the wp-config.php file, I preferred to change it directly in the database - for others reading this post, you're looking for the wp_options table, and you're going to browse for the options called 'siteurl' and 'home'. Thanks for the help, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically what is wrong is that you are not telling it what to do with that match.  The [L] by itself tells it that is the last rule to evaluate if it matches, but there is no action on that match.  The most typical case is [R] to perform a redirect.

If you are looking to redirect http://www.domain.com/ to http://www.domain.com/wordpress/ via a redirect, you should be able to do this simply with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /wordpress/ [R,L]
```

This will take a URL that has nothing after it (that is, just the www.domain.com) and redirect it to the relative path "/wordpress".  So when you hit www.domain.com/, you will get redirected to www.domain.com/wordpress/, but if you hit www.domain.com/wordpress/?pageid=1, or even www.domain.com/some_specific.html the rewriterule will not be hit, because it doesn't match the ^/$ rule.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, this didn't do anything. It's still going to /index.php on the root directory.

Comment: Looking at your regexp, wont that only work if I type: http:// www. mydomain .com/ <-- note trailing slash? If there's no slash, then this will not even trigger...

Comment: afaik, the R affects the browser. If it's not included, the rule will still do an internal redirect (R by itself issues a 302 redirect, R=301 issues...obviously...a 301 redirect). In some cases you don't want the browser url to change

Comment: Yes, this will only match if the URL ends w/ a slash.  However, browsers append that to the URL, so it should still work.  I tested in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/wordpress/? [L]
```

Comment: What does the '?' in your Regexp do?

Comment: let pass all the stuff after "wordpress/"

Comment: Are you sure? In the match part of the regular expression I believe that most symbols are treated literally (ie: you are actually putting a "?" into your address). See the documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule. Am I mistaken? Can you point me to documentation that supports this?